# How can I access a file on my local drive?

Tags: elm

In Elm, how can I access a file on my local drive?

For example, I need to access the file:

```
c:\MyFolder\somefile.txt
```

Comment: Just realized that this is a server side responsibility. However, I'll leave it here just because I'm curious.

Answer (score 2):

*(I'm assuming you're targeting the browser and not Node. If you want Node support, [**here**](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) is the documentation for it's `fs` module. The high-level usage will be similar to what I'm describing below for browsers.)*

There is not (yet) an Elm-only API for this, so you'll have to use ports. [**This article**](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) is very helpful, I will adapt its example.

In short, you have to use `File` and `FileReader` API ([caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=file)), and on load of the file send the data to Elm through port. (In my example below, Elm will get a `GetFile {name : String, content : String}` message for every file submitted.) [Here is a working example in Ellie.](https://ellie-app.com/gtDX2Cj8fa1/2)

**Msg:**

```
type Msg
    = GetFile File

type alias File =
    { name : String
    , content : String
    }
```

**Port:**

```
port getFile : (File -> msg) -> Sub msg
```

(don't forget `port module` instead of `module` on top of the Elm source)

**Subscription:**

```
subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    getFile GetFile
```

**HTML file input:**

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
```

**JS (the main part!):**

```
<script>

var app = Elm.Main.fullscreen();

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files;

  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

    if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
      continue;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          app.ports.getFile.send({name: theFile.name, content: e.target.result});
        };
        })(f);

    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
  }
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

</script>
```

EDIT: this example only accepts images. If you don't want that, remove the

```
if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
  continue;
}
```

part and do something different in the `viewFile` function (ie. don't try to interpret the `content` data as an image `src`).

Answer (score 1):

Elm is now able open files as of 0.19.

Steps are as follows:

1. Attach an event handler to a button that sends the appropriate message to the update function.
2. Update function receives message and runs the file-opening function, which tells Elm runtime to ask browsers to open a file selection dialogue.
3. Once user action has completed, Elm runtime returns a data of type File to the update function, and the update function can decide what to do.
4. To read file's content, a file-reading function has to be invoked. Again, the function tells the Elm runtime to read the content of the file. The runtime again invokes your update function, this time passing the content of the file.

Please refer to [this thread on Elm discourse](https://discourse.elm-lang.org/t/how-to-use-elm-file/3046/4), which includes [this example on Ellie app](https://ellie-app.com/4BDmZ3zwKFCa1)